# How to execute Opentest framework with chromium mobile feature enabled to run like an Ipad?

Tags: opentest

Does anybody know how to run the OpenTest automation with the feature of chromium running like an Ipad? 
I just could find something to test using Java, Javascript, and to execute using other languages codes. But nothing to run the OpenTest.

I also found this information at the [GITHUB from Selenium Webdriver](https://github.com/selenium-webdriver-book/source/)

```
Chrome Mobile Emulation
Specifying known device:

mvn ... -Dwebdriver.capabilities.browserName=chrome -Dwebdriver.capabilities.chromeOptions.mobileEmulation.deviceName="Apple iPad"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to simulate running on an iPad (or other tablet or mobile device), you can leverage the `selenium.resolution` parameter in `actor.yaml`:

```
# ...
selenium:
    resolution: 1024,768
# ...
```

If you want to test on a real iPad, either a local device or leveraging a cloud provider, that's possible too, by using the Appium functionality and the proper configuration of desired capabilities. Let me know if you need more information on that.